# Where is $\sqrt{2-z}$ analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Here $z^{1/2}$ is defined with respect to the principal branch of arg

How do I find where $\sqrt{2-z} $ analytic? I know 
$$\sqrt{2-z} = e^{\frac{1}{2}log_Iz}  $$
and I know $log_Iz$ is differentiable everywhere for  $\theta \in (-\pi , \pi)$
How do I find where the cut line of  $\sqrt{2-z} $ is from this?

I know the 2 will change $r$ to $r > 2$, but I don't know how $\theta$ changes.

Comment: How are you defining $\sqrt{2-z}$? The value with the smallest $\arg$?

Comment: The value with the principal arg. (See my edit) @DonThousand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a fair idea of what $\sqrt{2-z}$ is in relation to $\sqrt{z}$.

The function $\sqrt{z}$ is analytic everywhere *except* along its branch cut, which is the positive real axis*

Then, $\sqrt{z-2}$ is analytic everywhere *except* along its branch cut, which is the real axis for $x\geq2$.

Finally, $\sqrt{2-z}$ is analytic everywhere except its branch cut, which is the real axis for $x \leq -2$.

*We have to cut at the positive real axis, because when we say $\displaystyle ({e^{iz}})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ we either mean $\displaystyle e^{\frac{iz}{2}}$ or $\displaystyle e^{\frac{iz}{2}+\pi i}$, and so the function kind of "resets" when you pass along the branch cut.

I think that normally, rotations and translations *entire* function  are entire as well, however if there are some holes, poles, or branch cuts, you must translate them and rotate as appropriate.

Comment: when I solve it, I get that there are two regions in the $xy$ plane that don't work between the line $y = x-2$ and $y = 2-x$.

Comment: @Jess no, no. the branch cut is not y=x-2, and y=2-x... it is the real axis for x>2 and the real axis for x<-2